# How to use python to scrape the text from a page generated by javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, linux, selenium

I'm looking for a way on Linux to write a script that scrapes the text from a page which is generated by Javascript (specifically [etherpad](http://www.etherpad.org) e.g. http://www.board.net). Ideally I'd like to use an existing tool but I haven't found a suitable one (e.g. lynx, but it doesn't support javascript, or Selenium, but it runs in a browser). Suggestions welcome.

If there's nothing suitable (which would seem surprising for such a simple need), maybe I can write something myself in Python. What useful Python classes exist for something like this?

Comment: https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to still stick with [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), but use a headless [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

See also:

- [Headless Selenium Testing with Python and PhantomJS](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.U0_xQOZdXLY)

Example (using firefox webdriver):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://board.net/p/ThisIsBob%27sBoard/timeslider'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element_by_id('padcontent')
print element.text
```

prints:

```
Here is some text I'd like to scrape
 I wonder how to go about it?
```

Comment: I don't know Javascript myself, and it says it has a Javascript API. Is PhantomJS usable by somebody who doesn't know Javascript?

Comment: @user3149905 as far as I understand your task, you will write only a python code to get the data from a page you need. An example page you need to scrape would help me to help :)

Comment: @alexce: It looked to me like with PhantomJS I had to inspect a page for JS objects and then query them, or something like that, but I didn't study the API in depth. Here's a specific example page I just created that I'd like to be able to scrape: http://board.net/p/ThisIsBob%27sBoard/timeslider
I'd specifically like the date off that page.

Comment: @alexce: So if I understand it correctly, yes I'm only writing python code, but I am introspecting the JS code so I need to know how JS is structured and how it works to make sense of the result. I don't :)

Comment: @user3149905 you just need to get the necessary element by the id (or xpath, or name, or whatever - [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html)). See the update on the answer.

Comment: That's awesome - thanks. If I could vote this answer up, I would :)